# Is there an API in OSX to access Spelling API across applications?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Much like [Moom](http://manytricks.com/moom/) extends functionality of the NSWindow's close/open/minimise across applications. Is there access to the API's for OSX's spelling system?

To be more specific... is it possible to hook into an systemwide event for when there is a spelling mistake?

**Edit**
*I am guess if there was it would be through the Accessibility APIs*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSSpellChecker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpellChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for this purpose. Or if you want to just add regular spellckecking, You can enable spell-check for most of the text input fields.

```
[textView setContinuousSpellCheckingEnabled:YES];
```